# calling a time consuming method from a JButtonActionPerformed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

In the following lines of code when Button1 is pressed the Jframe becomes unresponsive till the execution of the encode() method is completed. But I need to update a progress bar in the Jframe displaying the progress.

```
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    try {
        if (flagState == 0) {
            WavFile.decode(readWavFile, msg.getText(), key.getText().hashCode());
        } else if (flagState == 1) {
            WavFile.encode(readWavFile, msg.getText(), key.getText().hashCode());            
        }
    } catch (WavFileException | IOException e) {
        notes.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I thought of doing this

```
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    try {
        if (flagState == 0) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                               public void run() {
                                  WavFile.decode(readWavFile, msg.getText(), key.getText().hashCode()); 
                               }
                            };)
            t.start();
        } else if (flagState == 1) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                               public void run() {
                                  WavFile.encode(readWavFile, msg.getText(), key.getText().hashCode()); 
                               }
                            };)
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (WavFileException | IOException e) {
        notes.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and update the progress bar from the encode() method.

But I understand that it will a strong coupling between the modules and i dont want that.

I also dont think that calling a new thread every time is a good idea (  thought of ExecutorService but   not sure how to use it).

What should I do to make this into a decent piece code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threading is definitely something you have to introduce here. Anything that takes a significant amount of time to complete should not be run in the awt event thread.

Spawning a new thread each time the button is clicked is not inherently a problem. You should consider, though, that it may be possible to spawn many threads doing the same thing before even the first completes. You could use an Executor if you want, but it probably is not necessary.

As for tracking progress, I would add another thread that periodically queries the other thread and updates the progress bar as necessary. Here's how I would structure it:

```
private void Button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    disableButton1();
    final Thread t;
    if (flagState == 0) {
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WavFile.decode(readWavFile, msg.getText(), key.getText().hashCode());
                } catch (WavFileException | IOException e) {
                    notes.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (flagState == 1) {
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WavFile.encode(readWavFile, msg.getText(), key.getText().hashCode()); 
                } catch (WavFileException | IOException e) {
                    notes.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Thread monitor = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (notComplete(t)) {
                    setProgressBar(getProgress(t));
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                }
                t.join();
            } finally {
                enableButton1();
            }
        }
    });

    t.start();
    monitor.start();
}
```

Comment: I never thought of the monitor thread.
I love this approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Thread monitor = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        ...
                    setProgressBar(getProgress(t));` That call should be scheduled for the EDT if 'progress bar' means `JProgressBar`.

Answer (score 1):

> n the following lines of code when Button1 is pressed the Jframe becomes unresponsive till the execution of the encode() method is completed. But I need to update a progress bar in the Jframe displaying the progress.

you have issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), you [block the EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), caused unresponsive GUI, until code ended

- have look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)
- use most scallable [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instread of [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- use implemented [setEnabled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) instead of  `if (flagState == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is what you need, there is no other nice way i can think of don't worry about calling new threads, that's what they are there for, jvm has a thread pool ready to be used, this sort of things runs really good with threads, try it out!

Create a class that extends Runnable, implement the run method or make it call your current method, that should be enough to do this.

Also you could just make it sleep for a short time and check the status each time the sleep time goes out, if the process finished you can continue, if not, back to sleep for another short time, that way you don't have to ask that many times.

I hope it helps.